# Installing sfGuard without changing db

Tags: symfony-1.4, sfguard

I am to integrate sfGuard plugin with existing application. What I want to do is to keep as much code as possible untouched. Any guides? It'd be perfect if I can use actual database schema, or bind it somehow to be used by sfGuard. I know about setting userProfile class but I'm not sure how should I get to it, not to destroy my app.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install plugin. And try make migrations. [doctrine::generate-migrations-diff](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks#chapter_16_sub_doctrine_generate_migrations_diff)

```
php symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff
```

And migrate [php symfony doctrine:migrate](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks#chapter_16_sub_doctrine_migrate) :

```
php symfony doctrine:migrate
```

Check out question: [Rebuild model without loss data in MySQL for Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138667/rebuild-model-without-loss-data-in-mysql-for-symfony/8139163#8139163)